# Is there a MariaDB equivalent of pgp_sym_encrypt from pgcrypto for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, pgcrypto

I've been tasked with migrating a Postgres 13 database to MariaDB. The existing Postgres database uses [`pgp_sym_encrypt`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) to encrypt certain values of data when inserting:

```sql
insert into a_table (
  normal_value,
  secret_value
) values (
  'normal',
  pgp_sym_encrypt(0.123::text, 'secret_key')
)
```

then decrypts it with:

```sql
select
  normal_value,
  cast(pgp_sym_decrypt(secret_value, 'secret_key') as double precision)
from a_table
```

Does MariaDB have something like this?
And what are my options when migrating existing data?

Comment: where is the specification of `pgkey_encrypt`?

Comment: Something like this = AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT

Comment: @danblack Added link. It seems pgkey_encrypt is an alias for pgp_sym_encrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Migrate to a AES ENCRYPT/DECRYPT**

Use postgres to change the value in the column to an AES_ENCRYPT/DECRYPT capable value and migrate this:

```
alter table a_table add secret_sym bytea;
update a_table set secret_sym = encrypt(cast(pgp_sym_decrypt(secret_value, 'secret_key') as bytea), 'secret_key'::bytea, 'aes-ecb/pad:pkcs'::text);
select cast(convert_from(decrypt(secret_sym, 'secret_key'::bytea, 'aes-ecb/pad:pkcs'::text), 'utf-8') as double precision) as decrypted_value from a_table
```

ref: [postgres fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w4zTWlMh)

Use MariaDB functions AES_DECRYPT/ENCRYPT which can now decrypt secret_sym.

```
select normal_value, aes_decrypt(secret_value, 'secret_key') from a_table
```

ref: [mariadb fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p-fLrcRu)

ref: noting hopefully soon non-ecb based [AES functions](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9069)

**Option 2: Create a PGP UDF**

There doesn't appear to be an existing PGP function in the server, and the collection of [UDF functions](https://github.com/orgs/mysqludf/repositories) doesn't appear to include it.

It is however pretty easy to use the [Rust UDF crate](https://docs.rs/udf/latest/udf/index.html) to create your own UDF functions.

The [pgp crate](https://docs.rs/pgp/latest/pgp/packet/struct.SymEncryptedData.html) appears to support symmetric PGP like Postgresql

A contribution request to the [Rust UDF](https://github.com/pluots/udf-suite) would be a good place to make your work available. If its beyond your ability/time availability you could just request it and offer to pay for its implementation.